# If $M=v_1v_i^TD_i$, compute $v_i$ and $D_i$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-linear-algebra

A known real-valued $n\times n$ matrix $M$ can be written as 
$$
M = v_1v_i^TD_i,
$$
(no summation on repeated indices) where the $v_i$ are orthonormal column vectors, $D_i$ are diagonal matrices and 
$1\leq i\leq n$.

---

**Knowing only $M$ with the properties stated above, how can the $v_i$ and $D_i$ be computed?**

---

Computing $MM^T$ we have
$$
MM^T=v_1v_i^TD_iD_jv_jv_1^T=(v_i^TD_iD_jv_j)v_1v_1^T=cv_1v_1^T,
$$
where $c$ is a real numberm. As this result must be true whatever $i$ or $j$, then the number $c$ must be the same whatever $i$ or $j$.  Now the vector $v_1$ can be computed through $MM^T=cv_1v_1^T$ and then be used to obtain
$$
v_1^TM=v_i^TD_i.
$$

And here is how far I could go. Obviously the diagonal matrix $D_1$ can also be computed, but I have no clue about how to get the other ones.

---

**Numerical Example**

Below there is an example of a matrix $M$with the properties stated above and a solution given by the orthonormal vectors $v_i$. The diagonal matrices can be easily computed. 
$$
M=\begin{pmatrix}
   0.14329 &  0.14545 &  0.14999 &  0.14607 &  0.18787  & 0.18648 &  0.14401\\
   0.15788 &  0.16026 &  0.16525 &  0.16094 &  0.20698  & 0.20547 &  0.15866\\
   0.10375 &  0.10532 &  0.10860 &  0.10576 &  0.13603  & 0.13503 &  0.10427\\
   0.15007 &  0.15233 &  0.15708 &  0.15298 &  0.19675  & 0.19531 &  0.15082\\
   0.11313 &  0.11484 &  0.11842 &  0.11533 &  0.14833  & 0.14724 &  0.11370\\
   0.11289 &  0.11459 &  0.11817 &  0.11508 &  0.14801  & 0.14692 &  0.11346\\
   0.11027 &  0.11193 &  0.11540 &  0.11240 &  0.14455  & 0.14350 &  0.11081
\end{pmatrix},
$$
and
$$
[v_1,v_2,\ldots,v_7]=
\begin{pmatrix}
0.4199104 &0.2134484 &-0.3097492& -0.3709365&-0.7358314&-0.0549746&0.0103221\\
0.4626576& 0.4298270& 0.2838626&-0.2988347& 0.4186424& 0.1090201& 0.4941353\\
0.3040402&-0.4154454&-0.1812354&-0.4642904& 0.3939669&-0.4718971&-0.3296302\\
   0.4397767 & -0.6990359 &  0.0094533 &  0.1918160 & -0.0817424 &  0.4438271  & 0.2782053\\
   0.3315402  & 0.1327565 & -0.3266486  & 0.6639579 &  0.0725541&  -0.5220768&   0.2170005\\
   0.3308324 &  0.3013229 & -0.2818176  & 0.1981848  & 0.2493111 &  0.4958764  &-0.6107427\\
   0.3231259&   0.0047608&   0.7774454&   0.2015631&  -0.2323336&  -0.2167151&  -0.3867475
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Comment: Could you give a reference to your first affirmation? I've never seen it before, and I want to be sure I answered it correctly.

Comment: For the matrix $M$? I have found  it!

Comment: Ok, then could you give a brief outline of the proof? I'm interested!

Comment: There is no proof @Milloupe. This matrix with these properties simply shown up when I was trying to solve a problem. That is all.

Comment: Ah, oops, sorry for misunderstanding.

Comment: Are you sure that there will be a unique solution? To me it doesn't seem that it should be the case.

Comment: I am sure about existence, as my example demonstrates, but not about uniqueness. Although there are strong constraints that indicates that an unique solution is highly probable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement that a matrix can be written as the product of two vectors
$$M = ab^T$$
means that it is a rank-one matrix, i.e. ${\rm rank}(M)=1$.

**NB:** Your numerical example has ${\rm rank}(M)=7$, so it **cannot** be the product of two vectors.

The particular form you have chosen
$$M=av^TD$$
reduces to the above canonical form by setting $\,b^T=v^TD$.

Let $m_k$ denote the $k^{th}$ column of $M$.

Then the $a$-vector is equal to **any** such column, after normalization.
$$a=\frac{m_1}{\|m_1\|}=\frac{m_2}{\|m_2\|}=\ldots$$
The components of the $b$-vector are simply the normalization factors.
$$b^T=\pmatrix{\|m_1\|&\|m_2\|&\|m_3\|&\ldots&}$$
The $b$-vector itself can be factored into a normalized vector and a scale factor.
$$\beta=\|b\|=\|M\|_F,\quad n=\frac{b}{\beta},\quad b=\beta\,n$$
This yields unique factorization of a rank-one matrix in terms of two unit vectors and a scalar factor.
$$M=\beta\,ab^T$$
This is, in fact, the Singular Value Decomposition of the matrix.

Comment: Thank you very much for your illuminating answer: right after I read it, it became clear *why* this matrix is emerging from my computations. There is only a small mistake: the numerical example *has* rank 1. You can see for yourself computing the determinant - it will give you a **very** small number - or computing $a$.